# eBay Developer API - GetSellerTransactions

Tags: java, ebay-api

I'm trying to obtain the shipping address of a buyer via the EBay Developers API however I am getting a NullPointerException. I do not understand why since I am sure the buyer has paid for the item and has a shipping address.

This is the code I'm using:

```
GetSellerTransactionsCall getSellerTransactions = new GetSellerTransactionsCall();
getSellerTransactions.setApiContext(getAPIContext());

Calendar calFrom = new GregorianCalendar();
Date todayFrom = new Date();
calFrom.setTime(todayFrom);
calFrom.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -29);

Calendar calTo = new GregorianCalendar();
Date todayTo = new Date();
calTo.setTime(todayTo);


TimeFilter modifiedTimeFilter = new TimeFilter(calFrom, calTo);

getSellerTransactions.setModifiedTimeFilter(modifiedTimeFilter);


TransactionType[] transactionType = getSellerTransactions.getSellerTransactions();

System.out.println("Size: " + transactionType.length);
// ^^ This returns 2 items as length


UserType userType = transactionType[1].getBuyer();


AddressType shippingAddress = userType.getShippingAddress();


String buyerFirstName = shippingAddress.getFirstName();
// ^^ This line causes a NullPointerException. Same error when I try to get the street address or any other shipping details of buyer. I can get the buyers email just fine using String email = userType.getEmail(); but no shipping details.
```